Magento 2.4.4p4 Rest API Trouble to Confirm Customer Registration
I am having trouble to activate this API to confirm user email upon registration

Request :
{
  "confirmationKey": "nVU3KFeGFg3Zn6L1oZlUbFaPclx3BOWN"
}

Response :
{
    "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "self"
    }
}

As you can see I am using the endpoint {{baseUrl}}/V1/customers/me/activate which the payload  seems to be correct already based on magento REST API documentation
The endpoint used for login is working fine

I have checked the value in the variable is correct and the endpoint is correct based on documentation, I am testing on fresh magento and also at my local project both are not working
I believe some explanataion and guide are needed to help me understand, Thank you
Update 13/6/2024: I am able to resolve the error after putting OAuth key on header, now I am getting this error,

